# Symlink target change not reflected by Apache + php-fpm with disabled opcache running in a podman container

Tags: php, apache, containers, symlink

The title mostly covers the whole problem: I have a setup where I use a link `/srv/www/latest` to point to the latest version of a project, which is deployed to a directory in `/srv/www`. `/srv/www` is a directory on the host mounted into a container that runs Apache+php-fpm. But when I change the target of the link, the path from which Apache actually delivers remains unchanged.

In quite a few places this problem is discussed and mostly explained by the use of php-fpm ([apache not reading updated symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363605/apache-not-reading-updated-symlink)) and/or how the PHP opcache works. But at least in my case, the problem persists

- when I clear the opache
- when I disable the opache
- when I set opcache.revalidate_path = 1
- when I execute `clearstatcache(true)` and
- when I kill and restart the php-fpm master process from inside the container

Only restarting the whole container makes the new link target active.

I have run out of ideas. Do you have any? PHP version is 7.4.30.